# Replace characters

Tags: arcgis-10.1, field-calculator

Using VisualBasic script or Python in ArcGIS 10.1, how can you remove a special number of characters of a string, e.g. the last 7 characters, and how to join them as the first characters to the string of another field?

Comment: What software do you use? ArcMap? Which version?

Comment: I'm using ArcMap 10.1

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Looking at your Question the only thing that ties it loosely to GIS is the inclusion of `arcgis-10.1` and `field-calculator` tags.  Even with these, such a Question which talks only about VBscript and Python would normally be closed as off topic for here and recommended for migration to StackOverflow.  Consequently, please take care to ensure that Questions you ask here are always [**on topic for GIS SE**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I thought stackexchange is the right board to get help with questions like mine. It is a problem quite refering to GIS. Do I have to shift it to another board?

Answer (score 3):

In python:

```py
def function(string1, string2):
    return string1[-7:] + string2
```

Then use:

```py
function(!field1_name! , !field2_name!)
```

Comment: I used this synthax and replaced field1_name and field2_name by my field names but it didn't work. Do I have to replace anything else? Shall I use both instructions in one step?

Comment: What type of fields are field1 and field2? If you have there integer, you have to convert it to string before return it to your new field. Also check what type of field has your third column which should contains the result (it must be "text"). First instruction paste to "Pre-Logic script code", and second instruction to the textbox below.

Comment: I didn't know that I have to create a third column. Where do I have to put that third one in the python synthax?

Comment: Simply, use field calculator on this column. You don't need to mention about it in python function. The returned value will be returned to this column.

Comment: I'm using field calculator exclusively. How does ArcMap know where to return the value? The execution failed --> error running expression: function(string1, string2) --> global name 'string' is not defined.

Comment: OK I've fixed this code - there should be "return string1[-7:] + string2" instead of "return string[-7:] + string2". Sorry for mistake :)

Comment: Thank you. In some cases it works. Sometimes there is still an error. Nothing is returned to the third column but to the one I wanted to change. How can I just remove any characters out of a string?

Comment: Would BatchEditingStringFields ArcToolbox be helpful ?